# form submit not woking when adding JS script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I know it's a stupid question, I searched on stackoverflow community but all the solutions talks about the submit method in javascript, I didn't quite understand the problem, here is a sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="go.php" id="registration-form" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center mt20">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Valider">
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- script  -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove one of the two scripts the code works, can anyone explain why ?

### Edit :

The content of `main.js` file :

```
/* I think this part that causes the problem

/*
 * Registration Form
*/

$('#registration-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var postForm = { //Fetch form data
            'fname'     : $('#registration-form #fname').val(),
            'lname'     : $('#registration-form #lname').val(),
            'email'     : $('#registration-form #email').val(),
            'cell'      : $('#registration-form #cell').val(),
            'address'   : $('#registration-form #address').val(),
            'zip'       : $('#registration-form #zip').val(),
            'city'      : $('#registration-form #city').val(),
            'program'   : $('#registration-form #program').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
            type      : 'POST',
            url       : './assets/php/contact.php',
            data      : postForm,
            dataType  : 'json',
            success   : function(data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').html("Registration Successful");
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').removeClass("alert-danger");
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').addClass("alert-success");
                                $('#registration-msg').show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').html("Registration Failed");
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').removeClass("alert-success");
                                $('#registration-msg .alert').addClass("alert-danger");
                                $('#registration-msg').show();
                            }
                        }
        });
});

/*
 * SmoothScroll
*/

smoothScroll.init();
```

Comment: You'll have to show us what's in `main.js`

Comment: Tell us, when does it work ? I mean when you remove which script it works ?

Comment: @adeneo is right. There must be some code in the main.js which is controlling the form. May be there's some code written with the id `registration-form` . I suspect it's jQuery `$("#registration-form").on("submit",function(){})

Comment: Your script prevents the form submit, and does an ajax call instead ?

Comment: @Nandan, when i remove one of them (whether it is the `main.js` or the `jquery.min.js`) I think problem is in the two files

Comment: Side-remark: [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is your friend. And get into the habit of caching your elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere this `smoothScroll.init()` is defined.
Comment the function call and check.

```
//smoothScroll.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you want your form to submit data? on `go.php` defined as form action? or on `./assets/php/contact.php` defined on your main.js? these are alternatives.

If you want to submit form using ajax, remove the action from your form. Also check the console to monitor your ajax requests.